# How can I get pay_key in IPN notification url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, payment-gateway, payment

I am using NodeJS adaptive payment module to create payment & to pay it,

I have configured IPN url in paypal profile & in my back end code.

I am getting transaction detail object. I want pay_key in response,

How can I get pay_key simply in my IPN notification response?

Answer (score 0):

When you run Pay, ExecutePayment API operations with IPN enabled in PayPal account, then PayPal will generate the IPN message with transaction details along with the paykey (pay_key). Its working for me. Refer the PayPal account IPN history section for viewing the generated IPN message variables.  [Click here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIPN/) for more information about PayPal adaptive payment IPN variables.

Comment: Plz share your IPN info here?